# Can't upload files

Tags: php, uploads, media

I've been developing a wordpress website (with a custom theme) for a month. Today I wanted to upload an image to a page and I got a message saying there was an error and I should try again later.

I tried to upload the image directly to the library and I got the following error:

> 1096 Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to delete buffer zlib output compression. in (...)/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2707

I deactivated all plugins, that didn't work. I tried changing the theme to twenty twelve, that didn't work. Is there anything I can do to fix this issue, or at least understand what this is all about?

Comment: Couple more things to check: Does your wp-uploads folder have the right permissions?  And do you still have free space on your server?

Comment: The wp-uploads folder have 777 permissions, and I still have free space on the server.

Comment: For security you shouldn't have higher than 755, but I'm afraid I don't have the answer then.

Comment: I just changed to 777 to test if that was the issue. Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a new Wordpress bug (I'm using version 3.5.2). Just set wp_debug to false and it works perfectly again. Hopefully they'll fix this soon.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```